# How to add LinkedIn link on contact section of ModenCV in Latex

Tags: moderncv

I want to add a LinkedIn link in the contact section of latex moderncv. How can I do that? I can add LinkedIN icon using

```
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\faLinkedinSquare linkedIN.com/in/johndoe
```

How to move this to the contact section with the hyperlink?

[image: I want to move the LinkedIn to the contact section on the right]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}

\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}

\firstname{John}

\familyname{Doe}

%\title{Curriculum Vitae}

\address{Address line 1..}

\mobile{(+91)....}

\email{jo@gmail.com}

\usepackage{marvosym}

\usepackage{fontawesome}

\faLinkedinSquare {linkedin.com/in/johndoe/}\

\quote{Curriculum Vitae}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Personal Information}

\cventry{Date of Birth}{26^th May 1992}{ }
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please provide a full MWE that we know which packages and template you're using. Otherwise it's not possible to help you.

Comment: @Steradiant, I used Overleaf as it follows,
`\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
%\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{Address line 1..}
\mobile{(+91)....}
\email{jo@gmail.com}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\faLinkedinSquare {linkedin.com/in/johndoe/}\
\quote{Curriculum Vitae}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Personal Information}
\cventry{Date of Birth}{26^th May 1992}{ }`

Comment: Probably something like `\extrainfo{\linkedinsocialsymbol \url{linkedin.com/in/johndoe/}}` works?

Comment: At least the `\begindocument` is missing for a full MWE. Please have a look [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). Imagine if we would have to build our own TeX file for each question and guess what the person asking is actually doing. That does not really motivate to help

Comment: Please see my added answer ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your given code I created an MWE for the current version of class moderncv, version 2.1.0. Using this current version you can use command `\social[linkedin]{john.doe}` to add your linkedin account to the contact informations ...

Please see the following MWE (important code changings marked with `<========`):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}

\name{John}{Doe} % <====================================================

%\title{Curriculum Vitae}

\address{Address line 1..}
\mobile{(+91)123454321}
\email{jo@gmail.com}
\quote{Curriculum Vitae}

%\faLinkedinSquare {linkedin.com/in/johndoe/}\ % <======================
\social[linkedin]{john.doe} % <=========================================

%\moderncvicons{awesome} % <=============================================


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Personal Information}

\cventry{Date of Birth}{26$^{th}$ May 1992}{ }{}{}{}% <=====================

\end{document}
```

and its resulting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]

If you want to use the glyphs of font fontawesome simply use command

```
\moderncvicons{awesome}
```

in your preamble to activate them (delete for testing the leading `%` in my MWE, line 23) and get the resulting pdf:

[image]